# Client-Server Chat application JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I have a simple java written client and server chat application(with sockets). When running on the same network/computer it works fine. However when i try to run the client from a different network it doesn't connect. I tried using the public IP address of the server to connect the client to the server but without luck. How would I be able to connect to the server app from a different network? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I did port forwarding on router. Most of the ISP provided modem/routers wont let you manipulate ports so had to buy my own modem/router, forwarded the port and worked like a charm. Information on what port forwarding is can be found here : `http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have more of a firewall issue than a problem with the application. Instead of trying to connect with the Java client, first try connecting with Telnet to the server from the same computer, then from the other computer. The first effort will show you what to expect when it works. For instance, if your server is running on port 999, use `telnet server.example.com 999`.

If the machines are Linux boxes, use `iptables -L` to see whether there is a block on the port you are trying to access.

If you're still having problems reaching the server, run `tcpdump -i tcp:999` on the server host to see what traffic is making it to your server socket, then run the telnet commands again. You should see the tcp connection established when connecting from the local machine, maybe or maybe not when connecting from other machines. If you don't see it while connecting from other machines, run `tcpdump` there too to make sure the client is definitely sending the traffic to the server.

After you are sure that the server can receive traffic and that your client is sending the traffic, there are no mysteries about what is actually going on and you should find your problem.

Comment: Here's my scenario, I'm using Ubuntu OS where my server-app is running on port 6789 on one network. And the other client-app is on mac running on the same port but on a different network. While compiling the client-app I need to provide the IP address of the server-app which the client needs to connect to. I cant seem to figure out which IP to give to client so that it will connect to the server-app. At this point I'm not even sure if it is possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas? @Brian Topping

Comment: Can the Mac SSH to the Ubuntu machine? If so, the networks are connected. I would guess at that if you do a ```telnet localhost 6789``` from the command line on the server, you will get a connection, correct?